# VS 2015 - Exclude a big folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to exclude a big folder (~13 000 files) from VS 2015. However, VS is not responding. Is there a command line I can use, or what is the best way of exclude this folder ?

Thanks !

Comment: You may just want to edit your .csproj / .xxproj file manually with a text editor.